# Using Combine to set up Publishers and while also satisfying requirement for initial values on non-nil variables

Tags: swift, swiftui, combine, watchconnectivity

I'm relatively new to reactive programming concepts, and I'm trying to build a simple view model to update `@Published Bool` values that are used to keep UI updated with SwiftUI.

This particular model is setting up those `Bool` values based on other values from the `WatchConnectivity` framework as they change over time.

Even though this is a simple example and it's working, I feel like I'm missing opportunities to reduce redundancy.

Specifically, it feels weird that I am repeating the logic used to set up the initial values of `appNotInstalled` and `complicationNotInstalled` later when I use `Publishers.CombineLatest` and `Publishers.CombineLatest3`.

Even though the initial values are passed through the publishers, so they go through the `CombineLatest` pipelines and set the initial values, it feels wrong to arbitrarily set the published variables to `true` or `false`, but the compiler is making me set initial values for them somewhere.

If I don't set initial values, I get the `Variable 'self.appNotInstalled' used before being initialized` error.

Is there a way I can avoid setting initial values, without making them nil, or another way to avoid duplicating the logic used to determine their values?

Here's the working code I have:

```
class WatchConnectivityModel: ObservableObject {

    // values used to show/hide UI
    @Published var appNotInstalled: Bool
    @Published var complicationNotInstalled: Bool

    private var cancellables: [AnyCancellable] = []

    init() {

        // initialize based on the values of everything at class init
        let activated = WCSession.default.activationState == .activated
        let appInstalled = WCSession.default.isWatchAppInstalled
        let complicationInstalled = WCSession.default.isComplicationEnabled
        appNotInstalled = !(activated && appInstalled)
        complicationNotInstalled = activated && appInstalled && !complicationInstalled

        // set up the publishers for any changes
        let activationStatePublisher = WCSession.default.publisher(for: \.activationState)
        let isWatchAppInstalledPublisher = WCSession.default
            .publisher(for: \.isWatchAppInstalled)
        let isComplicationEnabledPublisher = WCSession.default
            .publisher(for: \.isComplicationEnabled)

        // set up assignment of appNotInstalled for changes
        Publishers.CombineLatest(activationStatePublisher.removeDuplicates(),
                                 isWatchAppInstalledPublisher.removeDuplicates())
            .map { (state, installed) in
                // repeated logic from above
            return !(state == .activated && installed)
        }.receive(on: RunLoop.main)
            .assign(to: \.appNotInstalled, on: self)
            .store(in: &cancellables)

        // set up assignment of complicationNotInstalled for changes
        Publishers.CombineLatest3(activationStatePublisher.removeDuplicates(),
                                  isWatchAppInstalledPublisher.removeDuplicates(),
                                  isComplicationEnabledPublisher.removeDuplicates())
            .map { (state, appInstalled, complicationInstalled) in
                // repeated logic again
                return state == .activated && appInstalled && !complicationInstalled
        }.receive(on: RunLoop.main)
            .assign(to: \.complicationNotInstalled, on: self)
            .store(in: &cancellables)
    }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't the initial value set for `activationState` flow through the `activationStatePublisher` ?

Comment: @user1046037 The initial values do flow though the publishers, however I need to set the initial values for the two `@Published` variables somewhere before they're used. I could set them arbitrarily to `true` or `false` instead of initializing them with the real values (since that will happen anyway based on the initial publisher values) but that feels wrong and I'm wondering if there's cleaner way to write this.

Comment: I think you are setting values before the publishers have been subscribed. Move that setting of variables after the publishers are subscribed, so that they flow through.

Comment: @user1046037 Can you provide a code example? I’ve tried a lot of combinations but haven’t found a solution that avoids initializing the values of the two `@Published` variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a new initializer struct for each that just includes the logic for each. Whenever I set the initial values, or update the published variables, I use this to avoid duplicating the logic. I'm open to other possibilities if someone has a better solution to this.

```
import Foundation
import Combine
import WatchConnectivity

class WatchConnectivityModel: ObservableObject {

    // values used to show/hide UI
    @Published var appNotInstalled: Bool
    @Published var complicationNotInstalled: Bool

    private struct AppNotInstalled {

        let value: Bool

        init(_ activationState: WCSessionActivationState,
             _ appInstalled: Bool) {
            value = !(activationState == .activated && appInstalled)
        }
    }

    private struct ComplicationNotInstalled {

        let value: Bool

        init(_ activationState: WCSessionActivationState,
             _ appInstalled: Bool,
             _ complicationInstalled: Bool) {
            value = activationState == .activated && appInstalled && !complicationInstalled
        }
    }

    private var cancellables: [AnyCancellable] = []

    init() {

        // initilize based on the current values
        let state = WCSession.default.activationState
        let appInstalled = WCSession.default.isWatchAppInstalled
        let complicationInstalled = WCSession.default.isComplicationEnabled

        appNotInstalled = AppNotInstalled(state,
                                          appInstalled).value
        complicationNotInstalled = ComplicationNotInstalled(state,
                                                            appInstalled,
                                                            complicationInstalled).value

        // set up the publishers
        let activationStatePublisher = WCSession.default
            .publisher(for: \.activationState)
        let isWatchAppInstalledPublisher = WCSession.default
            .publisher(for: \.isWatchAppInstalled)
        let isComplicationEnabledPublisher = WCSession.default
            .publisher(for: \.isComplicationEnabled)

        // set up assignment of appNotInstalled
        Publishers.CombineLatest(activationStatePublisher.removeDuplicates(),
                                 isWatchAppInstalledPublisher.removeDuplicates())
            .map { (state, installed) in
                return AppNotInstalled(state, installed).value
        }.receive(on: RunLoop.main)
            .assign(to: \.appNotInstalled,
                    on: self)
            .store(in: &cancellables)

        // set up assignment of complicationNotInstalled
        Publishers.CombineLatest3(activationStatePublisher.removeDuplicates(),
                                  isWatchAppInstalledPublisher.removeDuplicates(),
                                  isComplicationEnabledPublisher.removeDuplicates())
            .map { (state, appInstalled, complicationInstalled) in
                return ComplicationNotInstalled(state, appInstalled, complicationInstalled).value
        }.receive(on: RunLoop.main)
            .assign(to: \.complicationNotInstalled,
                    on: self)
            .store(in: &cancellables)
    }
}
```